# get city name by latitude and longitude from OSM data stored in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, openstreetmap, osm.pbf

i know there are lot of similar question but after long time searchin none of them worked for me thats why i'm posting,

I want to get city name with lat and lon from planet_osm_polygon table where are polygons stored including polygons of cities, here is my code:

```
SELECT name
  FROM planet_osm_polygon
  where place = 'city'
 and ST_CONTAINS(ST_Transform(way,4326), ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(41.693459100461496,44.8014495),4326));
```

**(the logic is.. if polygon contains given point, return its name if its a city)**

What is the problem? i transformed both geometries to 4326 but still not working. P.S "way" is a column of geometry(polygon).

**Query always returns empty result**

**Edit**

City is not missing from planet_osm_polygon and its geometry column really is type of polygon, here is some query results:

[image: Cities query]

[image: In geometry viewer it looks correct]

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the database structure. The city node https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/1614277087 is probably not contained in planet_osm_polygon since it is a node, not a polygon. Or is this supposed to return the corresponding relation https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/1996871?

Comment: Can you share 1) sample data, 2) the error you're getting and 3) the expected result?

Comment: @scai thanks for taking a time to help me, I updated post and added some more details.

Comment: @JimJones i updated post, check it out

Comment: @Martian it would be nice to actually see the geometries in a more friendly format, e.g. WKT `SELECT name,ST_AsText(way) FROM planet_osm_polygon` - and please post the result as text, not in a screenshot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're switching x and y in your coordinate pairs. [`WGS84`](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/) expects `longitude, latitude`, not the other way around:

```
SELECT name
FROM planet_osm_polygon
WHERE place = 'city'
AND ST_Contains(ST_Transform(way,4326), ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(44.80,41.69),4326));
```

On a side note: Consider reducing the precision of your coordinates. With so many decimal numbers you're entering the microscopy realm -> `41.693459100461496`

Sample data

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE planet_osm_polygon (name TEXT, way GEOMETRY,place TEXT);
INSERT INTO planet_osm_polygon 
VALUES ('Georgia',ST_SetSRID('POLYGON((43.87 42.22,45.43 42.22,45.43 41.50,43.87 41.50,43.87 42.22))'::GEOMETRY,4289),'city');
```

The coordinates correspond to the following BBOX in the SRS `4289`:

[image]

Query - point inside the BBOX, setting either BBOX and given point to `WGS84`

```
SELECT name
FROM planet_osm_polygon
WHERE place = 'city'
AND ST_Contains(ST_Transform(way,4326), ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(44.80,41.69),4326));

  name   
---------
 Georgia
(1 Zeile)
```

[image]

Comment: yes i was copy - pasting coordinates  from google maps for testing and forgot to switch coordinates, thanks.